# When is it safe in Go to reference an object only through a `uintptr`?

Tags: go, garbage-collection

The Go Programming Language says in Section 13.2 that this is code is safe and `x` will always
be visible to the garbage collector:

```
pb := (*int16)(unsafe.Pointer(
  uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&x)) + unsafe.Offsetof(x.b)))
*pb = 42
```

And that this code is unsafe, because `x` is temporarily not visible to the
garbage collector, which could move it, making `pb` a dangling pointer:

```
tmp := uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&x)) + unsafe.Offsetof(x.b)
pb := (*int16)(unsafe.Pointer(tmp))
*pb = 42
```

But I can't see the difference between these two examples.

In the case described as safe, after `uintptr` has been called, the only
reference to the `x` is the `uintptr` value, isn't it? There's a `Pointer`
to it on the same line, but it was an argument to `uintptr`, which has run,
so nothing is referencing the arguments, and so the `Pointer` is not live and the `uintptr` is the only reference to the object.

I can't see how storing the `uintptr` in a local variable instead of as an
expression intermediate value makes it any more safe. Aren't local variables
like `tmp` removed in compiler phases anyway, becoming anonymous dataflow edges,
so that the generated code should be semantically equivalent? Or does Go have
some rules for when garbage collection can run? Such as having safepoints only
between statements? But the code in the first example has method calls so I
would presume they would always be safepoints?

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem with 'assign it (so it can't be GC'ed)' are you saying that the version that uses the temporary variable is the safe one? That's the opposite of what the book says though. And as I say, the two programs seem equivalent to me. I can't see the semantic difference between them, assuming at least a basic optimising compiler.

Comment: Deleted my comments, I got things backwars... too tired, got confused thinking about C sequence points

Comment: Simply put, `x` could be garbage collected between the assignment to `tmp` and the assignment to `pb`

Comment: @JimB: Found the reference. It's not `x` that is the key. It's `tmp` being an integer rather than a reference, and not being managed/updated that makes the second snippet unsafe. The wording in the book/docs is a bit counter-intuitive, must be said

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: yes, the conversion from an integer to a pointer is what's actually unsafe; I thought it would be easier to understand in this example that what might happen is the value pointed to is garbage collected and may no longer exist. The spec is clear, but people often confuse the specification with the implementation.

Comment: This is a question about the spec and not the implementation right? Because the current Go GC never moves anything so both examples should be the same in practice as long as x is live the whole time.

Comment: Yes it's hypothetical I admit. But the book give it as such a specific example so I thought it must be there to imply something about when Go have safepoints or something like that. Maybe not.

Comment: @TristanHume: Not quite, I've done some more digging and [this](https://github.com/golang/proposal/blob/master/design/17503-eliminate-rescan.md) is a good read to get a high-level overview on how the GC works. The key being the STW phase, and preventing to move objects etc... still going through it looking up the references to find the definitive answer to this question (probably will take some time for this after work)(

Answer (score 2):

Found the reference I hinted at in my comments [here](https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/#Pointer)

> A uintptr is an integer, not a reference. Converting a Pointer to a uintptr creates an integer value with no pointer semantics. Even if a uintptr holds the address of some object, the garbage collector will not update that uintptr's value if the object moves, nor will that uintptr keep the object from being reclaimed.

What this means is that this expression:

```
pb := (*int16)(unsafe.Pointer(
  uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&x)) + unsafe.Offsetof(x.b)))
*pb = 42
```

Is safe because you're creating a `uintptr`, which is seen as an integer, not a reference, but it's immediately assigned (unless there's a race condition somewhere else, the object that `x` references cannot be GC'ed) until *after* the assignment). The `uintptr` (again: integer type) is also immediately cast to a pointer, turning it into a reference so the GC will manage `pb`. This means that:

- `uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&x)) + unsafe.Offsetof(x.b))`: all safe, because `x` clearly is an existing reference to an object
- `pb` is assigned an integer that is (through the cast) marked as a reference to an `int16` object

However, when you write this:

```
tmp := uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&x)) + unsafe.Offsetof(x.b)
pb := (*int16)(unsafe.Pointer(tmp))
```

There is a chance that, between assigning `tmp` (remember integer, not reference), the actual object in memory is moved. As it says in the docs: `tmp` will *not* be updated. Thus, when you assign `pb`, you could end up with an invalid pointer.
think of `tmp` in this case as `x` in the first case. Rather than being a reference to an object, it's as if you wrote

```
tmp := 123456 // a random integer
pb := (*int16) (unsafe.Pointer(tmp)) // not safe, obviously
```

For example:

```
var pb *int16
tmp := uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&x)) + unsafe.Offsetof(x.b)
go func() {
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    pb = (*int16)(unsafe.Pointer(tmp))
}()
// original value of x could be GC'ed here, before the goroutine starts, or the time.Sleep call returns
x = TypeOfX{
    b: 123,
}
```

Comment: "but it's immediately assigned" But what I am asking is what stops the garbage collector running in the middle of this statement? Why can't the GC run after the pointer has been converted to an integer, so moving the object and invalidating the integer? Does Go guarantee it won't have GC safepoints in the middle of a statement? How can that work when there are method calls in the statement? Every language with a GC I've seen has safepoints on method entry points.

Comment: @ChrisSeaton: By immediately assigned I mean: the assignment takes place _before_ x has a chance to change (Go's GC is a stop-the-world GC after all). There's also no reason for the object referenced by `x` to be GC'ed, because `x` still exists. In the second case, `x` can be moved, reassigned, ... before you convert the integer type `tmp` to a pointer (ie reference to object). I've tried to find information on golang sequence points and the like, but haven't really spent a great amount of time on that

Comment: Bottom line is that, although in the case where `tmp` is assigned directly before you're assinging `pb`, and there's no concurrency issues, it's highly unlikely the second snippet will cause problems, but in the last example I included (with the sleep and reassigning `x`), then `pb` is likely to be unsafe

Comment: I still don't get it, sorry. We (a) get a pointer to an object, (b) convert it to an integer, then (c) convert that integer to a pointer again. I don't see why the GC couldn't run after (b) has run and just before (c) runs, move the object, and mean that your integer is no longer pointing to the object. I know that the Go GC is stop-the-world, but I don't see how the compiler would know that it was not safe to stop the world in the middle of this statement.

Comment: @ChrisSeaton: It can run then, but because `x` references the same object still, the object you point to will still exist. Say the integer value is 1234, that address will still be valid between (b) and (c), because `x` holds a reference to that object. The only way that can change is if you have a race condition that changes x in a routine at the exact same time. This is possible, but is caused by you not handling concurrency properly, not by the operation as such. I'd say that that's why concurrency + `unsafe` is a bad idea without `atomic` and `sync`

Comment: By contrast, in the second snippet, `tmp` is managed for what it is (an integer). By the time you assign `pb`, there's a bigger chance for things to go wrong. Like I said: in this specific case (2 lines of code), it's extremely unlikely, but it's technically possible. I'll have a look during lunch into golang sequencing points, and see if go offers more guarantees WRT `x` being moved or GC'ed while it's being referenced in an expression that is being evaluated. If not, then your scenario (something happening between (b) and (c) is impossible, making the first version completely safe)

Comment: Interesting question BTW +1 :D

Comment: But the object in a `Pointer` can be moved can't it? So `x` references the object, but the object can be moved and `x` updated by the GC, but nobody updates the `uintptr` version. Thanks for trying to explain it but I still don't get it so I must be missing something fundamental and I'll stop going back and forth with you. Thanks!

Comment: @ChrisSeaton: Fair enough, [this document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/16Y4IsnNRCN43Mx0NZc5YXZLovrHvvLhK_h0KN8woTO4/edit) might be worth looking at. It's from way back when they started revamping the GC stuff. Basically, the way the go GC works I gather that `x` is not changed when there is an operation like `&x` + `offsetof`, because if `x` were to move between evaluating these two expressions, the result is UB. I _believe_ the first version basically blocks the GC to work on `x` entirely until the entire statement has been resolved, and no side effects remain, not so in the 2nd case